# How can I access the specified precision when implementing Debug?

Tags: rust, string-formatting, traits

I have a simple structure for holding intervals of `f64`s:

```
pub struct Interval {
    pub min: f64,
    pub max: f64
}
```

This code prints with hardcoded 3 decimal places:

```
impl fmt::Debug for Interval {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "[{:.3?} {:.3?}]", self.min, self.max)
    }
}
```

I want to support `println!("{:.6}", my_interval)` to be able to print with desired precision.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html#method.precision

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, use [`Formatter::precision`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html#method.precision). There is already an example of this [in the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html):

```
impl fmt::Binary for Vector2D {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        let magnitude = (self.x * self.x + self.y * self.y) as f64;
        let magnitude = magnitude.sqrt();

        // Respect the formatting flags by using the helper method
        // `pad_integral` on the Formatter object. See the method
        // documentation for details, and the function `pad` can be used
        // to pad strings.
        let decimals = f.precision().unwrap_or(3);
        let string = format!("{:.*}", decimals, magnitude);
        f.pad_integral(true, "", &string)
    }
}
```

For your case:

```
impl fmt::Debug for Interval {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        let precision = f.precision().unwrap_or(3);
        write!(f, "[{:.*?} {:.*?}]",  precision, self.min, precision, self.max)
    }
}
```